How to fix - 'global' is not defined" no-undef
In the new eslint flat file config, how to fix this?
I have already added the below and is not working.
import globals from "globals";

      globals: {
        ...globals.browser,
        ...globals.jest,
      },

but this is not fixing this issue. Any help is appreciated.

The 'global' not being defined is referring to a Node global:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/globals/blob/main/data/nodeBuiltin.mjs#L30
So adding ...globals.node should do the trick:
globals: {
  ...globals.browser,
  ...globals.jest,
  ...globals.node,
},

